# Complex signal representation: convolution I and Q or I+iQ

Tags: digital-communications

I work on a constant envelope GMSK modulation. If  I use the complex signal ( I + iQ) in `conv`, it works perfectly and if I want to rewrite it in baseband ; I and Q , it doenst work.

Assume `cmpl_sig` in the code above is an input. I convolve it with gaussian filter:

```
cmpl_sig_f = conv(h_gaus, cmpl_sig, 'full');
cmpl_sig_f = cmpl_sig_f / max(abs(cmpl_sig_f ));
```

and if I do it for I and Q :

```
I_cmpl_sig_f = conv(h_gaus, real(cmpl_sig), 'full');
Q_cmpl_sig_f = conv(h_gaus, imag(cmpl_sig), 'full');

I_cmpl_sig_f = I_cmpl_sig_f / max(abs(I_cmpl_sig_f ));
Q_cmpl_sig_f = Q_cmpl_sig_f / max(abs(Q_cmpl_sig_f ));
```

In convolution theory I know I can split it [* - convolution]:

$$  (a+b)*c = a*c + b*c$$

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> I_cmpl_sig_f = I_cmpl_sig_f / max(abs(I_cmpl_sig_f ));
> Q_cmpl_sig_f = Q_cmpl_sig_f / max(abs(Q_cmpl_sig_f ));
> ```

your normalization is wrong. That's all. max(abs) is not the same as max(real) is not the same as max(imag), which means you're scaling I and Q differently, what you clearly don't want. Also, don't normalize to a sample maximum at all, that's bad – if you want a defined power, normalize your impulse response!

Comment: thank you for your reply